# PHP - Selecting Multiple columns from a database

Tags: php, forms, search, multiple-columns

```
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if($x==1) 
        $construct .="Name  LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
        $construct .="AND Name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM Rating, Attraction WHERE $construct" ;
```

---

**I have the columns Name, Summary, Description, OpeningHours, Address, Postcode**

What I want to do is trigger all these columns in the '$construct' query that includes LIKE '%$search_each%'

What would be the structure, I have tried OR, AND and UNITE

I have run out of ideas.

Comment: What is the value of `$construct`
After iteration of foreach loop

Comment: Would you like to check whether *ANY* of the search words appears in *ANY* of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

use `concat_ws()` like this:

```
$construct ="SELECT * FROM Rating, Attraction WHERE
concat_ws(Name, Summary, Description, OpeningHours, Address, Postcode)
LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

Hope it work ...

Comment: Although now my database information is repeating its self and displaying the echos 12 times each, 12 is the number of rows I have in the database. Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this? I have tried break; but then that only produces one result in my search...

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = array('Name', 'Summary', 'Description', 'OpeningHours', 'Address', 'Postcode')
foreach($columns as $column) {
    $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search[$column]);
    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {
        $x++;
        if($x==1) 
            $construct .="$column  LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        else
            $construct .="AND $column LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }
}
```

You have to remember that `$search` is now an array which has search entries as string values for each column key.

Comment: Thanks a lot the reminder! I know have problems with duplicate results, is this something to do with multi-dimensional arrays. I have tried using a break; in the echo but this reduces the search to one result always, thanks.